# How to figure what is the path for a javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node.js with Express.
I'm trying to figure how to indicate the path to my javascript file:

qcode-decoder.min.js

my folders:

```
myProject/
  -- server.js
  -- app/routes.js
  -- views/pages/wallet.ejs
  -- bower_components/qcode-decoder/src/qcode-decoder.min.js
```

in server.js, I have: require('./app/routes.js')
in routes.js I have:

```
app.get('/wallets/:walletId', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  ...
  res.render('pages/wallet', {...}
}
```

(Express will look in "views/pages/wallet.ejs")

the url is:
    http://localhost:3000/wallets/560bf7b08841d1ff0d741932

in wallet.ejs I have:

```
<script src="bower_components/qcode-decoder/src/qcode-decoder.min.js"</script>
```

and in my browser console I have this error message:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/wallets/bower_components/qcode-decoder/src/qcode-decoder.min.js
```

There is no "wallets" folder. If I try with src="../bower_comp......
I still have an error mmessage:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/bower_components/qcode-decoder/src/qcode-decoder.min.js
```

My question is how to figure which path I must indicate for my script?

Comment: missing / in scr: 
<script src="/bower_components/qcode-decoder/src/qcode-decoder.min.js"</script>

Comment: "missing /" : did not change anything